# Manter Bean vivo mesmo depois de um redirect - JSF

Tags: jsf, jsf-2.2, cdi

Alguém sabe alguma maneira de deixar um Bean vivo mesmo depois de dar um redirect?

A situação é assim: estou desenvolvendo um projeto em que, na teoria, o usuario fizesse login e o usuário e senha que ele digitou fiquem salvas em algum lugar (provavelmente junto com o bean) até que ele clique em LogOut.

Eu procurei uma solução na internet e encontrei o Flash do JSF porém no flash ele não guarda os dados pra sempre, ele perde os dados depois de 2 ou mais redirects, testei também o @ConversationScoped do CDI porém o bean morre quando eu dou redirect então eu não sei como manter esse bean vivo, alguém pode me ajudar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode colocar na sessão atributos e/ou objetos que serão mantidos até que ela seja destruída. Meu código abaixo se refere á um método de uma classe que obtêm o e-mail do cliente setado por outro método, tudo dentro da mesma sessão que pode ser pego em qualquer Bean.

```
@SessionScoped
@Named
public class SessaoObjeto implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public String obterClienteEmail() {
        HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext()
                .getRequest();
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
        HttpSession session = (HttpSession) request.getSession();
        String email = (String) session.getAttribute("CLIENTEID");
        return email;
    }

public void inserirClienteEmail(Cliente cliente, boolean clienteLogado) {
    FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    HttpSession session = (HttpSession) fc.getExternalContext().getSession(false);
    session.setAttribute("LOGADO", clienteLogado);
    session.setAttribute("CLIENTEID", cliente.getEmail());
}
```

Utilizo desta forma para sempre que eu precisar dos dados é só utilizar estes métodos =D Espero ter ajudado